# Android splash screen width

Tags: android-activity, width, splash-screen

I'm new to this forum and new to Android development. I'm making my first app (according to "Practical Android 4 Games Development" book by J.F. DiMarzio) and the problem is very common as I saw-the splash screen width doesn't fit. Splash image is in 9patch format. It scales well in heght, but there is always a little margin on left and right side. How can I eliminate that?

I'm writing code identically as it is in the book so I don't have any idea what's wrong.

[Splash image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T37lD.jpg)

splashscren.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/splashScreenImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:src="@drawable/sfstart" >

    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/creditsText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:text="@string/bottom" >

    </TextView>
</FrameLayout>
```

And MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //usuwa title bar
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
}    }
```

please help me!

EDIT:
I found a solution in related thread- added android:scaleType="fitXY" to ImageView section in .xml file. Maybe it will be helpful for someone :)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is just how the splash image is created - with some black or transparent on the left and right. May be you should open the spalsh image in 9patch tool and post a screen capture of it.

Comment: I could not understand exactly what I saw in your link :) - I was expecting some other view of it. But from what I saw I think there is indeed something on the left and right edge of the 9 patch, which would explain your problem. Anyway you can upload the original 9patch file?

Comment: http://speedy.sh/rdG8z/sfstart.9.png here it is. This one has other patches which work fine for me. As I said, scyletype="fitXY" was very helpful.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution. Glad you find it :)